# complete.cases for group instead of observation?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

If I have tidied data:

```
df = expand.grid(Name=c("Sub1","Sub2","Sub3"),Vis=c("Yes","No")) %>%
       mutate(KPR_mean=c(NA,1,3,2,3,2),KPR_range=c(NA,4,4,2,6,5)) %>%
       filter(complete.cases(.))
```

I'd like to filter out incomplete factor combinations, to be left with a full factorial model. Right now, I'm doing so as follows:

```
df %>% 
  unite(KPR_mean_range,KPR_mean,KPR_range) %>%
  spread(Vis,KPR_mean_range) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  gather(Win,KPR_mean_range,-Name) %>%
  separate(KPR_mean_range,c("KPR_mean","KPR_range"),sep="_")
```

But that seems really verbose, and also difficult to extend once there are multiple factors and more variables.  Is there a way to filter on a grouping variable, instead of a row? I.e., for each level of Name, if filter(complete.cases(.)) would remove a row from that group, then remove the entire group instead?

Comment: Could you share your data reproducibly (e.g., with `dput()`)? It's a pain to read the example data you posted into R with the column classes in there.

Comment: Even this is not working for you I guess, since the `unite` step concatenate `NA` as `NA_NA` and the `complete.cases()` doesn't work on character `NA_NA`.

Comment: I would probably figure out how many rows per subject are expected and filter out groups that have fewer rows than that. Something like `n_expected = length(unique(df$Vis)); group_by(df, Name) %>% filter(n() == n_expected)`.

Comment: @ Gregor: Oops, I never realized that's how you had to do it. I replaced it with some made-up data in the same form.

Comment: Changing the data changed the result of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the new data, expand your answer to all cases, group by whichever variable you want the completed cases in, and filter out groups with `NA`s:

```
df %>% complete(Vis, Name) %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(!any(is.na(KPR_mean)))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: Name [2]
# 
#      Vis   Name KPR_mean KPR_range
#   (fctr) (fctr)    (dbl)     (dbl)
# 1    Yes   Sub2        1         4
# 2    Yes   Sub3        3         4
# 3     No   Sub2        3         6
# 4     No   Sub3        2         5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' specifying the key columns, (`setDT(df,..`), do a cross join, grouped by 'Name', if there are no 'NA' values in 'KPP_range', subset the group of rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = c("Name", "Vis"))[CJ(Name, Vis, unique=TRUE)][,
             if(all(!is.na(KPR_mean))) .SD , Name]
#   Name Vis KPR_mean KPR_range
#1: Sub2 Yes        1         4
#2: Sub2  No        3         6
#3: Sub3 Yes        3         4
#4: Sub3  No        2         5
```